# 'openstack ip availability list/show' in Python API

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-api

I would like to use this openstack command using the Python API. Going through the Neutron documentation, I found this [page](https://github.com/openstack/python-neutronclient/blob/15d99a7d68435132fd2fbd4ba604c3796802a83e/neutronclient/neutron/v2_0/network_ip_availability.py).

I tried executing 'network_ip_availability.ListIpAvailability(neutron.list_networks())' but it I get a 'TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)'.

I cannot figure out what else does it need aside from a list of networks to display its IPs.

Any help in understanding on how to use these commands in Python API will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use the CLI, or use the Python API in your own application?

Comment: Hi @dvnguyen, I am hoping to just use API for my script.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use that internal API, but use the public one [here](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/index.html#user-guides).
You'll need:

1. Install the openstacksdk using pip `pip install openstacksdk`
2. Get a Openstack connection object with your credentials. See more at [connect guide](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/guides/connect.html)
3. Use the connection object above to access Openstack resource. For instance, here the guide to access [network resource API](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/guides/network.html).
4. And finally, use the network API to get [available floating IPs](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/network.html#floating-ip-operations)